# Show text in ListView instead of collection

Tags: wpf, listview

I use a `ListView` with a `GridView` view to display results of a search. I'd like to display an informative message (something like “No elements found”) in the middle of the `ListView` in the case when there are no elements to display. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF listbox empty datatemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699881/wpf-listbox-empty-datatemplate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change ListView template with trigger in style when ListView has no items, like this:

```
    <ListView Name="List" 
              DockPanel.Dock="Top"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Serial" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Serial}" />
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListView">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                             Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <ListView>
                                            <ListView.View>
                                                <GridView>
                                                    <GridView.Columns>
                                                        <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Serial" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Serial}" />
                                                    </GridView.Columns>
                                                </GridView>
                                            </ListView.View>
                                        </ListView>
                                        <TextBlock Text="No items..."/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>
    </ListView>
```