# How to display a default value for WPF ListBox bound to an empty list

Tags: wpf, listbox, default-value

If the Bounded List is empty I want to display a default message in the listbox like "No Items Present"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should a textBlock on top of the listbox, and bind its visibility to the collection also, using a converter that would convert null to Visibility.Collapsed.

```
<Grid>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TheItems}" />
  <TextBlock Text="No Items Found" 
    Visibility="{Binding TheItems, Converter={StaticResource TheConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

and the converter:

```
public class NullToInvisibleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value==null ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: in your Visibility binding you can bind to ItemsControl's HasItems Property and use a plain BooleanToVisibilityConverter. That way your solution still works if the ItemsSource changes and you don't have to implement your own ValueConverter

Comment: Now got it working using this syntax: <TextBlock Text="No items."      Visibility="{Binding HasItems,ElementName=ListBoxContacts,Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityNegationConverter}}"/>

Answer (score 1):

use this method which is using Datatrigger of the listbox .

[WPF listbox empty datatemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699881/wpf-listbox-empty-datatemplate)