# In XAML using ItemsControl if !Source.Any() technique to show "No records" Label

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Record.Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

There's a situation where Items.Any() is actually zero.

Is there a better way than this to show that there are no records?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Record.Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
<TextBlock Text="No Records" 
    Visibility="{Binding Record.Items.Count, Converter={MyVisibleWhenZeroConverter}}" />
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: just have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699881/wpf-listbox-empty-datatemplate

Comment: Absolutely clever. I could not get it to work globally, but on individual ListBox it's a charm. Very nice. Better than my suggestion in the question because it actually replaces the ListBox template. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can define a Style with a DataTrigger (Items.Count -> 0) for the TextBlock, then you do not need to use a converter, but that could be seen as a matter of preference i suppose.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Record.Items.Count}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```