# Binding itemsource with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF listbox empty datatemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699881/wpf-listbox-empty-datatemplate)

The Itemsource of my Itemscontrol is binded to an ObservableCollection. How can I write the code so that it shows the text "The list is empty" if there are no objects in the ObservableCollection.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" Name="itemsControl2" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentPatients}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the `TargetNullValue`

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue

You can add it like

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" Name="itemsControl2" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentPatients, TargetNullValue=The list is empty}">
```

Comment: Well would it work with an empty list instead of Null?

Comment: Good point, check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699881/wpf-listbox-empty-datatemplate

Answer (score 0):

i use a style for this

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ItemsControl}" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <TextBlock Text="The list is empty" 
                                       FontFamily="{StaticResource FontFamily}"
                                       FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize}"/>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <TextBlock Text="The list is empty" 
                                       FontFamily="{StaticResource FontFamily}"
                                       FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize}"/>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this logic in C# view model.  No need to change your xaml code.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private ObservableCollection<string> recentPatients = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private IList<string> emptyList = new string[] { "This list is empty" };

    public MainPage()   {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.recentPatients.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }
    public IList<string> RecentPatients {
        get { return recentPatients.Any() ? recentPatients : emptyList; }
    }
    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)     {
        if (this.recentPatients.Count <= 1) {
            // It could be a change between empty to non-empty.
            this.OnPropertyChanged("RecentPatients");
        }
    }
    // implement the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern here.
```